# View serial device output in console in hex

Tags: linux, zsh, serial-port, hexadecimal, hexdump

I'm able to convert my serial device output to hex format doing these two commands:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > data.dump #send some data to serial device, and interrupt cat using Ctrl+C after some time
xxd data.dump
```

It gives me output like:

```
00000000: 80ff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff       ..............
```

But I want to do that in one command, to see live data stream, but neither of these commands works for me:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | xxd
xxd /dev/ttyUSB0
hexdump /dev/ttyUSB0
```

These commands gives me no output at all, what is the problem here? I'm using `zsh` shell, and working on fedora OS.

Comment: This is probably, because the pipe is buffered, maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe gives you a clue how to work around that.

Comment: How about `tail -f`?

Comment: `xxd /dev/ttyUSB0` should work, but it only outputs in chunks of 16 bytes, so you have to give it 16 bytes first, or change the formatting somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from /dev/ttyUSB0 is unfortunately not so simple.  This [solution on the Unix & Linux SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372096/200533) worked best for me.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 raw -echo   #CONFIGURE SERIAL PORT
exec 3</dev/ttyUSB0                     #REDIRECT SERIAL OUTPUT TO FD 3
  cat <&3 > /tmp/ttyDump.dat &          #REDIRECT SERIAL OUTPUT TO FILE
  PID=$!                                #SAVE PID TO KILL CAT
    echo "R" > /dev/ttyUSB0             #SEND COMMAND STRING TO SERIAL PORT
    sleep 0.2s                          #WAIT FOR RESPONSE
  kill $PID                             #KILL CAT PROCESS
  wait $PID 2>/dev/null                 #SUPRESS "Terminated" output

exec 3<&-                               #FREE FD 3
cat /tmp/ttyDump.dat                    #DUMP CAPTURED DATA
```